# Serverside ecommerce transaction push to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I'm trying to push an ecommerce transaction with minimal information 
to analytics, following are two method implementation of it but none 
seem to work. These methods are constructed by referring to the 
documentation and code snippets on forums.

```
    public static void pushToGoogleAnalytics(String analyticsCode, String 
domain, String product_sku, String product) { 
                Map<String, String> params=new TreeMap<String, String>(); 
                params.put("utmwv", 4+""); 
                params.put("utmn", new Random().nextInt(2147483647)+""); 
                params.put("utmhn", domain); 
                params.put("utmipc", product_sku); 
                params.put("utmipn", product); 
                params.put("utmtid", product_sku); 
                params.put("utmdt", product); 
                params.put("utmp", "/"); 
                params.put("utmhn", domain); 
                params.put("utmac", analyticsCode); 
                params.put("utmcc", "__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B"); 
                try { 
                        byte[] response = URLUtils.get(new URL("http://www.google- 
analytics.com/__utm.gif"), params); 
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
        } 




      public static void pushToGoogleAnalytics(String analyticsCode, String 
domain, String product_sku, String product) { 
                String var_utmac = analyticsCode; 
                String var_utmhn = domain; // domain 
                String var_utmn = random(1000000000,2147483647)+""; // random number 
                String var_cookie = random(10000000,99999999)+""; //random cookie 
number 
                String var_random = random(1000000000,2147483647)+""; //number under 
2147483647 
                String var_today = Utils.getNow().getTime()+""; 
                String var_uservar="-"; // no user-defined 
                String urchinUrl="http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif? 
utmwv=3&utmn="+var_utmn+"&utmipc="+product_sku+"&utmipn="+product 
+"&utmtid="+product_sku+"&utmdt=test&utme=&utmcs=-&utmsr=-&utmsc=- 
&utmul=-&utmje=0&utmfl=-&utmdt=-&utmhn="+var_utmhn+"&utmhid="+var_utmn 
+"&utmac="+var_utmac+"&utmcc=__utma%3D"+var_cookie+"."+var_random 
+"."+var_today+"."+var_today+"."+var_today+".2%3B%2B__utmz 
%3D"+var_cookie+"."+var_today+".2.2.utmcsr%3D_SOURCE_%7Cutmccn 
%3D_CAMPAIGN_%7Cutmcmd%3D_MEDIUM_%7Cutmctr%3D_KEYWORD_%7Cutmcct 
%3D_CONTENT_%3B%2B__utmv%3D"+var_cookie+"."+var_uservar+"%3B"; 
//              urchinUrl=urchinUrl.replace("&", "&amp;"); 
                byte[] response = URLUtils.readURL(urchinUrl); 
                System.err.println("google analytics push URL: "+urchinUrl); 
        }
```

Comment: Does it have to be server side?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this article](http://bit.ly/1f4AQZC) I've recently published about pushing data to Google Analytics via Python.

Note that it gives you only the bare minimum and you can easily convert it to your favourite language. You'll need to add e-commerce related parameters though.

Comment: Here is the updated link https://medium.com/python-programming-language/80eb9691d61f

Comment: Thanks, updated the link. Let me know if the post works for you.